# How to use a component library from nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js

When I try to load typescript icons within a monorepo... I get this error.

Not sure why this happens because my nextjs project is a typescript project.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { StyledAppIcon } from './AppIcon.styles';
| 
> export interface AppIconProps {
|   iconSize?: string;
|   padding?: string;
```